# Test require() clause in constructor

Tags: testing, unittesting

I am writing a test suite to ensure that parameters in my smart contract's constructor are being properly validated by a require() statement prior to any gas expenditures.

I have been looking through truffle's documentation but all the examples thus far relate to calling functions of successfully instantiated contracts with require() clauses.

My code is as follows:

```
contract MyContract is ERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    constructor(
        uint256 total, 
        uint256 constituent, 
        uint256 otherConstituent
    ) public ERC20("Name", "SMBL") {
        require(constituent.add(otherConstituent) <= total, "error!");


        // Other code
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to test this case using Truffle's tooling?

Comment: Truffle, and other Solidity SDKs, can catch reverts and the relevant messages. Thus, your test will test for the revert message presence in the deployment transaction. How do to this with Truffle, please look up the documentation as I do not program in Truffle anymore myself.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using open zepellin's test helpers library:

```
const { expectRevert } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");

contract("MyContract Tests", async (accounts) => {

    it("Tests a throw", async () => {
        await expectRevert.unspecified(
            MyContract.new(100, 200, 3);
        );
    });

});
```